# How to handle NSDictionary ObjectForKey JSON feed errors crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am working on an app which consumes a JSON Feed but have found that if the Feed is incorrect or has missing objects it will cause my app to crash.

This is the feed we are receiving currently, normally when the web service is working we will receive an ID

```
    result =     {
        data =         {
            result =             (
                "<null>"
            );
        };
        success = 1;
    };
}:
```

I am currently parsing the feed like this

```
NSDictionary *results = [json objectForKeyOrNil:@"result"];
NSString *success = [results objectForKeyOrNil:@"success"];
NSDictionary *data = [results objectForKeyOrNil:@"data"];
NSDictionary *resultsArray = [data objectForKeyOrNil:@"result"];
```

Finally we are doing this to try and get the object which is missing

```
NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKeyOrNil:@"id"];
```

And at this point the app crashes

The category class I am using objectForKeyOrNil I was hoping would prevent the crash but that seems to not work either.

```
- (id)objectForKeyOrNil:(id)key {
    id val = [self objectForKey:key];
    if ([val isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    return val;
}
```

Crash message received 
-[NSNull objectForKeyOrNil:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x248e678

I thought I would update the original post here a few people have suggested checking the ID when I do this it still crashes

```
NSDictionary *resultsArray = [data objectForKeyOrNil:@"result"];
// Loop through the downloaded data
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in resultsArray) {

    id val = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
    if ([val isEqual:[NSNull null]] || val==nil) {
    }

    NSLog(@"Should be OK");
```

With the code above it never reaches the NSLog statement

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 2):

you just have to check id, whether it is null or not. or you can return blank in place of nil. then may be it wont crash

```
- (id)objectForKeyOrNil:(id)key {
    id val = [self objectForKey:key];
    if (val ==[NSNull null]) 
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return val;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test whether it equals to `[NSNull null]` before you map it.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it still crashes  id serverID = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
            if (serverID != nil && [serverID class] != [NSNull class]) {

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
- (id)objectForKeyOrNil:(id)akey {
    id object = [self objectForKey:aKey];
    if (object == nil ) {
        return @"";
    }
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]) {
        return object;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for all the replies I think I have actually solved it I was trying to get the value from a key which didnt exist in the firs place .

Adding this code to check if the key exists first helped me capture the error:

```
    if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"id"] != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Key does not exist");
    }
```

Thanks for all the help

Aaron

Comment: That code is nonsense. First, you should use objectForKey. valueForKey is something completely different and highly dangerous with JSON data. Second, your test is of course wrong. != nil means something exists. == nil means it doesn't exist. == [NSNull null] means your JSON document contained a null value.